# How do I install a Wimax usb driver?

Tags: drivers, usb, modem

I am using wimax usb modem in Ubuntu 9.04 properly. I am familiar with Ubuntu 10.04 and try to install the same deb file to use my wimax USB modem, but it could not install and give me the following error message:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i green-packet-wimax-usb_i386.iso.deb 
(Reading database ... 206628 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace green-packet-wimax-usb 1.12 (using green-packet-wimax-  usb_i386.iso.deb) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/green-packet-wimax-usb.prerm: 45: /etc/init.d/wimaxd: not found
Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/wimaxd ...
FATAL: Module mt7118_usb_os not found.
Unpacking replacement green-packet-wimax-usb ...
Setting up green-packet-wimax-usb (1.12) ...
FATAL: Error inserting mt7118_usb_glue (/lib/modules/2.6.32-28-generic/kernel/drivers/net/mt7118_usb_glue.ko): Invalid module format
dpkg: error processing green-packet-wimax-usb (--install):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for python-gmenu ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/desktop.en_US.utf8.cache...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

The error (Line 9) give me some clue that the `mt7118_usb_glue.ko` kernel object can't insert it. So, I think this may be due to it's kernel dependencies.

Can anybody tell me how I can install this kernel object to my new Ubuntu 10.04 kernel?

Comment: Any interested also have a look at this: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/139831

Answer (score 0):

what's the provider name? Qubee or Banglalion ? and also which usb modem? if u are using banglalion, (I am just guessing) [see this link](http://forum.projanmo.com/topic31242.html)

It's in Bangla & for Ubuntu 11.10 and [this](http://forum.projanmo.com/topic30579.html) for Ubuntu 11.04

I guess you have to install newer Ubuntu version.

Comment: Jahid vai it's qubee. And i saw the link you provided here previously. So how can i forcefully install the kernel object file in this newer kernel. Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10

Anyways try this on the version you have

To get the driver for Wimax installed , just type the following using the Terminal:

To open Terminal: Ctrl+Alt+T

Type in the following commands:

```
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install madwimax
```

Have fun!!!